# cmake finds path to opencv library but make does not find opencv function Rodrigues

Tags: c++, opencv, makefile, build, cmake

I am building a project from [github](https://github.com/anhttran/3dmm_cnn). This project uses `OpenCV`. `cmake` is used for building the project. The output of cmake is as follows:

```
OpenCV information:
  OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS: /usr/local/anaconda3/envs/test-caffe/include/opencv;/usr/local/anaconda3/envs/test-caffe/include
  OpenCV_LIBRARIES: opencv_xphoto;opencv_xobjdetect;opencv_ximgproc;opencv_xfeatures2d;opencv_tracking;opencv_text;opencv_surface_matching;opencv_structured_light;opencv_stereo;opencv_saliency;opencv_rgbd;opencv_reg;opencv_plot;opencv_optflow;opencv_line_descriptor;opencv_hdf;opencv_fuzzy;opencv_face;opencv_dpm;opencv_dnn;opencv_datasets;opencv_ccalib;opencv_bioinspired;opencv_bgsegm;opencv_aruco;opencv_videostab;opencv_videoio;opencv_video;opencv_superres;opencv_stitching;opencv_shape;opencv_photo;opencv_objdetect;opencv_ml;opencv_imgproc;opencv_imgcodecs;opencv_highgui;opencv_flann;opencv_features2d;opencv_core;opencv_calib3d
-- Boost version: 1.54.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   filesystem
--   system
Boost information:
  Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS: /usr/include
  Boost_LIBRARIES: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_filesystem.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so
  Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
OPENMP FOUND
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/iimtech5/3DMM/3dmm_cnn-master/build
```

As you can see, `cmake` has found `opencv` directories. But here's the error thrown by `make` command:

```
/home/iimtech5/3DMM/3dmm_cnn-master/modules/PoseExpr/src/BaselFaceEstimator.cpp:207:2: error: ‘Rodrigues’ is not a member of ‘cv’
cv::Rodrigues(rMatP, rVec);
  ^
make[2]: *** [modules/PoseExpr/CMakeFiles/PoseExprLib.dir/src/BaselFaceEstimator.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [modules/PoseExpr/CMakeFiles/PoseExprLib.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Can anyone suggest me why could this error be coming? I have tried all the means to know the implication of this error but failed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you including opencv in your cpp file?  I think it is more an include problem than a cmake problem

Comment: @api55 Looks like a flakey library - C++ code, but only includes the old [`cv.h` and `highgui.h`](https://github.com/anhttran/3dmm_cnn/blob/master/modules/PoseExpr/include/BaselFaceEstimator.h#L3)...

Comment: @api55 Its not my code. Its a project from github (I have provided the link). So, its clear that the code should have worked for the author before he uploaded it to github. Hence, I don't think it has anything to do with code, but with the environment I am building it on. If you have any clue about what the error is about, please tell me.

Comment: It could be the opencv version, it says 2.4.6 or better (but it has to be 2.4.x, not 3.x.x, they changed quite a lot in 3). It seems the person that created the github project also used deprecated headers (cv.h) which does not include `opencv2/calib3d/calib3d.hpp` which you can include in such file, or include `opencv.hpp`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I shall try both: getting right version of opencv and if that does not help, updating the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have installed openCV on your linux: 
OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS: /usr/local/anaconda3/envs/test-caffe/include/opencv;/usr/local/anaconda3/envs/test-caffe/include

This above path is for opencv in python

Install opencv using : sudo apt-get install libopencv-dev